# sqlite3 varchar matching with "like" but not "="

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Rails 3.1 and sqlite3 for development, test environments.

Added a new table in a migration:

```
create_table :api_keys do |t|
  t.string :api_key
  t.integer :user_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

This produces a table with the following schema:

```
create_table "api_keys", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "api_key"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

In ActiveRecord model:

```
before_create :fill_api_key

private

def fill_api_key
  self.api_key = SecureRandom.hex(30)
end
```

ActiveRecord's dynamic finder method `find_by_api_key(api_key)` does not work (returns nil). Same with:

```
ApiKey.where({:api_key => 'something'}).first
```

In sqlite3, I do the following:

```
insert into api_keys (id, api_key) values (-1, '12345');
```

If I now run a select:

```
select api_keys.* from api_keys where api_keys.api_key = '12345';
```

the record will be found.

Pre-existing data created from my app is displayed if I run an unfiltered select:

```
select api_keys.* from api_keys;
```

If I try to find a pre-existing record by pasting into my query a long hex string from one of those pre-existing records:

```
select api_keys.* from api_keys where api_keys.api_key = 'long hex string';
```

then it returns no results. If I try this instead:

```
select api_keys.* from api_keys where api_keys.api_key like 'long hex string';
```

Then I get a match.

I have created an index on api_keys.api_key but that had no effect.

This problem affects one other model in my application that produces a similar string of random hex digits using Digest::SHA1::hexdigest instead.

James

Comment: I should add that this worked on the second model class I mentioned up until upgrading to Rails 3.1. The tests started failing at that point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I think I've figured it out. The problem isn't that this is Rails 3.1, it's that you've likely moved from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.2.

In Ruby 1.9, all strings are now encoded. By default, all strings should be `UTF-8`, however, `SecureRandom.hex(30)` returns an encoding of `ASCII-8BIT`.

You can confirm this in sqlite3 by using this command: `.dump api_keys` and you'll probably see that the api_key field looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO "api_keys" VALUES(1,X'376433356530[...]',1);    
INSERT INTO "api_keys" VALUES(1,'1234567890[...]',1);
```

The first one is the api_key generated by SecureRandom. The second is the one created by typing into the console. The X indicates the field is encoded as a blob, not as a string.

To get around this, change your `fill_api_key` to this:

```
self.api_key = SecureRandom.hex(30).force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

I just got bit ***big time*** by this, so hopefully it helps you out.

There are some good details about the changes to String in 1.9 here: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick. I'm not sure how I missed the X in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using strings of hex digits, it is important that you have a case match if you want to use an where x = y select. Unlike some databases, SQLite is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That doesn't seem to be it -- I'm copying and pasting the string within sqlite3 -- it's all lower case, I'm using all lower case and I'm copying the literal string directly.

Comment: Ok, in your example above, the INSERT you chose has no alpha hex digits. What happens if you use '1a3bf7' or something like that when you do the INSERT in SQLite directly. Does the SELECT find it? Does your Rails app? Also, how long is this hex string?

Comment: Hex string is 60 char in length (perhaps overkill). In my testing, I typed strings of decimal digits as long as 70 chars and then started adding letters (lower case, at the start) up to about 80 chars.

Comment: I'll start by saying I'm stumped. But what happens if you do a rake db:drop && rake db:create, then try the same stuff. I'm just guessing here, but something seems odd about how the alpha characters are being interpreted.

Comment: The second table I had mentioned has data from before and after the upgrade to Rails 3.1. Records that pre-date the update can be found with select ... where field = 'value' but records created after cannot (but "like" works). It appears to be something with the string. It makes me think maybe it has something to do with character encoding.

Comment: The SQLite docs imply that it is not too picky about accepting characters with different encodings (http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html). That's why I suggested drop and create -- to make sure the encoding is uniform. There's a thread on, of all places, the Blackberry support forum (http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/UTF8-encoding-and-SQLite-database-problems/td-p/462189) where someone had almost exactly the same problem you describe with hex digits. See if that sheds any light on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3534/discussion-between-steve-ross-and-james-roscoe)