# Activerecord can't find model by attribute, even though the query is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

I have a Model called `Invitation` which has an attribute called `code`. The application's goal is to find the correct invitation with a code that is entered somewhere.

My problem is, however, that even though the input is correct, ActiveRecord can't seem to find any results while querying in the database. I've created this small test to illustrate the problem:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > code = Invitation.first.code
Invitation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" LIMIT 1
=> "86f50776bf"
```

So at this point I've loaded this invitation's code in a variable

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > i = Invitation.where(:code => code)
Invitation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."code" = '86f50776bf'
=> []
```

And the response of the query is an empty array, even though the code comes straight from the database. When using `code == Invitation.first.code` to see if the values are equal, it returns `true`. I already checked both the Ruby and database's data types, they're all Strings.

What can cause this? and how can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you execute that SQL directly?

Comment: Same, although – I forgot to mention – when I use `LIKE` instead of = it does find it.

Comment: To add, this is the code that generates the `code` in the first place (on initialisation of the model): `self.code = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(5) if self.code.blank?`. I already tried putting to_s after it, but that has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution when I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437944/sqlite3-varchar-matching-with-like-but-not/7465390#7465390):

> In Ruby 1.9, all strings are now encoded. By default, all strings should be UTF-8, however, SecureRandom.hex(30) returns an encoding of ASCII-8BIT.

Adding `.force_encoding('UTF-8')` to the key when it's being executed solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it could be the case that the column is not `VARCHAR` but `CHAR`, or it contains trailing spaces that are being trimmed off by the ActiveRecord ORM layer or the database driver. `'foo'` and `'foo  '` are not equivalent, but they are `LIKE` enough to match.

You may want to switch that column to variable length, or to adjust your query to test: `RTRIM(code)=?`

Comment: Hmm, I used an app to check the sqlite file but the `code` field is a `VARCHAR` and there are no trailing spaces in the rows, tnx for the tip though

Comment: Woah, pretty good guess. I would have never thought about that :)

Comment: No it doesn't. It seems, though. This might be a stretch, but it seems that after I've actually submitted a form to that particluar `invitation` row, the query does work. Could it be that there's something wrong with the way it's stored initially?

Comment: If you can replicate this, have a look at what `HEX(code)` returns. This should be `38366635303737366266` for your example of `86f50776bf`. If there's additional bytes at the end you may have padding issues.

Comment: Hmm… The hex is the same, so no extra values. When I also `HEX` the input value, both values are the same

Answer (score 0):

@Marco,

How you declare the code variable? As String?

Example:

```
code = "86f50776bf"
```

or

```
code = '86f50776bf'
```

?

Comment: In the above code I'm directly assigning it from the result of another query (`Invitation.first.code`), and in the actual app I am assigning it from a `session[:code]` variable. Even if I directly assign it in the console (with double quotes mostly) the effect is not different.