# Rails: using binary value to query a binary column returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, binary

I have a binary column which contains 256-bit checksums. I can store the checksums ok, but when I try to query via the checksum, nothing is returned.

```
d = Digest::SHA2.new
d.update "large str i'm creating the hash with"
begin
    codebase = Codebase.find_or_create_by_checksum(d.digest)
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
    # handle duplicate record error
end
```

I've tried where and different versions of find. Nothing returns. When I use find_or_create_by_checksum, since it doesn't find anything it tries to create it and an exception is raised since I have a uniq index on the checksum column, but still I need to be able to get the record with the matching checksum.

```
    create_table :codebases do |t|
        t.binary :checksum, :null => false, :limit => 32
    end

    add_index :codebases, :checksum, :unique => true, :name => 'name_of_the_codebas_uniq_index'
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you please post the appropriate section of your `db/schema.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if its binary on the database, I couldn't reproduce:

migration:

```
class Checksum < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :checksums do |t|
        t.binary :checksum, :null => false, :limit => 32
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

And then trying it on the rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > Checksum.create(:checksum => digest.digest)
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "checksums" ("checksum") VALUES (?)  [["checksum", ",&\xB4kh\xFF\xC6\x8F\xF9\x9BE<\x1D0A4\x13B-pd\x83\xBF\xA0\xF9\x8A^\x88bf\xE7\xAE"]]
 => #<Checksum id: 1, checksum: ",&\xB4kh\xFF\xC6\x8F\xF9\x9BE<\x1D0A4\x13B-pd\x83\xBF\xA0\xF9\x8A^\x88bf\xE7\xAE"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > Checksum.first
  Checksum Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "checksums".* FROM "checksums" LIMIT 1
 => #<Checksum id: 1, checksum: ",&\xB4kh\xFF\xC6\x8F\xF9\x9BE<\x1D0A4\x13B-pd\x83\xBF\xA0\xF9\x8A^\x88bf\xE7\xAE"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > Checksum.find_by_checksum(digest.digest)
  Checksum Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "checksums".* FROM "checksums" WHERE "checksums"."checksum" = x'2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae' LIMIT 1
 => #<Checksum id: 1, checksum: ",&\xB4kh\xFF\xC6\x8F\xF9\x9BE<\x1D0A4\x13B-pd\x83\xBF\xA0\xF9\x8A^\x88bf\xE7\xAE">
```

So it works as expected.....

Comment: It is a binary in the database. I've updated the question to show the table schema. I thought about storing the hexdigest string and this is a viable workaround. Still curious though as to why this doesn't work with binary. Hmm..

Comment: Wierd, I did the same thing you posted and Codebase.find_by_checksum(d.digest) returns nil. Maybe something wrong with my configuration (ruby 1.9.3-p0, activerecord 3.1.1)?

Comment: Ok let's try to get rid of the encoding variable...when you save do force_encoding("UTF-8"), like: Checksum.create(:checksum => d.digest.force_encoding("UTF-8")

Comment: I've started with a fresh table like yours.

Comment: Funny thing I noticed, when digest has empty string loaded I can find the record, update the digest with non-empty string, all find returns nil. UTF-8 didn't do the trick either. Using force_encoding in create works normally. Using it in find (Checksum.find_by_checksum(d.digest.force_encoding("UTF-8"))) I get "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Comment: Yeah, just force_encoding when create not when find. It is an encoding problem if it works with empty strings and not with others. Try forcing_encoding before save.

Comment: I tried with Digest::MD5 object...even empty string doesn't work. Tried with Digest::SHA1 object and all queries are so far working! It concerns me that SHA2 worked some of the time but not all the time. Makes me feel a bit unreliable about storing these as binary and having all queries work as they should.

Comment: SHA2, non-empty str, force_encoding to UTF-8 on create but not on find: query still returns nil.

Comment: That's why I always encode anything that comes from 'openssl' as a hex or base64. I also usually force UTF-8 on them. Change checksum to string and use hexdigests you'll be good.

Comment: If you ever find out why binary doesn't always work let me know. Until then I'll use hex strings. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Strings are encoded in UTF-8 blobs are not. Your string goes through several transformations before they get to the DB. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437944/sqlite3-varchar-matching-with-like-but-not